# MySQL write wrong data

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm testing my PHP application. I'm trying to write with a mysql query a string value in a decimal field (eg. table field is 'price' (decimal) and I try to write 'hello' string). I expected a sql error, but I receive only a warning and in the table I can see a row with '0.00' in the 'price' field.

I need to break the mysql insert and return an error to my php app.

**Note:** I need to test the value of the field via mysql, not via PHP with is_numeric() or similar functions.

Comment: What is wrong with testing the value via PHP?

Comment: testing for writing text to a decimal field in mysql is useless. A proper written program would not allow it to happen. So don't test for it, there is no use.

Comment: @MarcoPace This is my code :INSERT INTO `prices`(`id`, `product_id`, `price`) VALUES (1,10,'abc') NOTE: price filed is decimal (15,2).

Comment: @Erbureth : there aren't problem via PHP , but I need to test via mysql.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: Why can't you just test it via php?

Answer (score 1):

Data validation in mysql could be performed using triggers but i would strongly recommend to validate your data within your application context.

http://rpbouman.blogspot.ch/2009/12/validating-mysql-data-entry-with_15.html